# How to limit the resources of process submitted by non-slurm on CentOS

Tags: slurm

We have a cluster with 1 node, 200 CPU cores and 2T RAM. The server are shared by 15+ people and required to submitted job by slurm.(*computing node and login node are on same machine*). But some people are unwilling to do so!

So, is there a way to limit the resources of user's process submitted by cmd, but no by slurm?
For example, a no-slurm job shouled be restricted with `CPU:2, RAM:4G`;

```bash
$ resource-consuming-program  # job submitted by cmd should be restricted.

$ cat slurmjob.sh
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -J TEST
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=700G

# We recommend using SLURM to run resource-consuming job.
resource-consuming-program  
$ sbatch slurmjob.sh  # job submitted by SLURM won't be restricted.
```

All in all, we just want to limit which tasks that are not submitted by SLURM. Thanks. ☺️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a ad-hoc solution to your problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526994/limit-resources-cpu-mem-only-in-ssh-session. The idea there is to constrain users in a `cgroup` whenever they are in an `SSH` session.

Other than that, there is a tool called [Arbiter2](https://github.com/CHPC-UofU/arbiter2) that was created for the purpose of controlling usage resources on login nodes.

Comment: Hi, I tried the method and it work. Due to the `/etc/profile.d/ssh.sh` run by login user instead of `root` and the `tasks` file permission is `775` for group members to write, if login user know the path of this file(ie. `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/customssh/limit/tasks`), he/she can get rid of this restriction by removing the pid of login shell. 